# Why does my linq expression only work when broken into two parts?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I've got this linq expression

```
po_data.POItemQuantiyReceived = NDCEntity.tbl_Ext_Mobile_Receipt_Item.Where(Function(p) po_data.POItems.Select(Function(r) r.UID).ToArray().Contains(p.MobilePOItemUID)).ToArray()
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Guid[] ToArray[Guid](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Guid])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Which I took to mean it had some trouble generating the array og Guids I needed to do the Cntains. But when I split it up into two statements:

```
Dim test As Guid() = po_data.POItems.Select(Function(r) r.UID).ToArray()
po_data.POItemQuantiyReceived = NDCEntity.tbl_Ext_Mobile_Receipt_Item.Where(Function(p) test.Contains(p.MobilePOItemUID))
```

It works fine. Is this one of those issues where Linq needs a.. well, not a constant, but something similar? In the past I've run into circumstates where I needed to move a variable from, say, a Dictionary into just a local variable for LINQ to work. Is this one of those instances? Or is there a way to do this all in one line like I want.

Comment: The reason is that your expression must be converted to a SQL query before it is sent to the database.  The error is telling you that it doesn't how how to translate the ToArray method to SQL.  When you split it up, the ToArray method of the first line is not sent to the database, only the part inside the Select method is.  The ToArray in  that case happens on the client.

Answer (score 3):

The second code executes two separated SQL queries, and that's why it works.

To make the first working remove `ToArray` call before `Contains`:

```
po_data.POItemQuantiyReceived = NDCEntity.tbl_Ext_Mobile_Receipt_Item.Where(Function(p) po_data.POItems.Select(Function(r) r.UID).Contains(p.MobilePOItemUID)).ToArray()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't fix it. I get the error `Unable to create a constant value of type 'MobileSAPWebServices.tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO_Item'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.` `tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO_Item` is the type of the items in po_data.POItems